# require 'modename vs require 'modename-install

Tags: org-mode, init-file, configuration-files

I hope to use org files for my configuration. And I found some use `(require 'org-install)`, and some use `(require 'org)`. Any differences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the comments inside `org-install.el` in Emacs 26.1:  "*The file `org-install` is obsolete.*"   There is nothing inside that file except some comments about backwards compatibility, a `provide` statement and some file-local variables.  Therefore, use `(require 'org)` to load the main library.

---

**Q**:  How did I learn about that?

**A**:  Type `M-x find-library RET org-install RET` and read the few lines of code.